# lag-return with dplyr using lag within mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataset looks like and I want to create lag variables of "value" based on "id" and "t"

```
id       t    value
001   200001  1
001   200002  1.5
001   200003  0.75
002   200001  1
002   200002  1.58
002   200003  0.5
```

I used the following code:

```
orig <- rownames(d)
d <- d[order(d$id,d$t),]
t <- d %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(
  R1 = lag(value,n=1),
  R2 = lag(value,n=2),
  R3 = lag(value,n=3))
```

The code creates something like.

```
id       t    value  R1  R2 R3
001   200001  1      1   1  1
001   200002  1.5    1.5 1.5 1.5
```

and so on..

The desired output should look like this:

```
id       t    value  R1  R2 R3
001   200001  1             
001   200002  1.5    1  
001   200003  0.75   1.5  1  
002   200001  1      
002   200002  1.58   1  
002   200003  0.5    1.58 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Your code works fine here, but this depends on your desired output, can you show us how your output should look like? 2. You don't need `orig <- rownames(d)`, since you do use it after assignment in your example.

Comment: edited in the question. Thanks.

Comment: This is basically the output I get when I run your code. Can you try to run your code in a new session? Alternatively use `dplyr::lag` to avoid namespace conflicts.

Comment: Yes, works now! Thank you very much for your help - namespace conflicts would have been the last thing I was looking for...